# What are the event arguments "sender" and "e"

Tags: vb.net

I'm struggling to understand these arguments.
They are automatically generated and I don't need to give them much thought but if I want to call one of these events from some other part of the form then I need to supply these arguments with values - not easy as I'm still unsure what they mean.

Here is the event I'd like to `Call`:

```
Private Sub stringButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles stringButton.Click
    Dim outString As String
    Select Case stringTextBox.Text
        Case ""
            outString = "You entered an empty string"
        Case "10"
            outString = "10"
        Case Else
            outString = "Your string is not covered by the cases"
    End Select
    strResultTextBox.Text = outString
End Sub
```

Here is the calling method:

```
Private Sub stringTextBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles stringTextBox.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Call stringButton_Click(Me, Me) '<<(Me,Me) is my incorrect attempt
    End If
End Sub
```

What arguments should I use and why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303145/net-events-what-are-object-sender-eventargs-e This question should help you.

Comment: You don't need the `Call` statement btw.

Comment: In `VBA` I usually include `Call` just to make things more readable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DON'T call event handlers from other parts of your code! This is very sloppy coding. Create a separate method that does what you need, with the parameters you need, and call it both from the event handler and any other part of your form, eg

```
Private Function String GetResponseMessage(ByVal input as String)
    Select Case input
        Case ""
            Return "You entered an empty string"
        Case "10"
            Return "10"
        Case Else
            Return "Your string is not covered by the cases"
    End Select
End Function

Private Sub stringButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles stringButton.Click
    Dim outString As String=GetResponseMessage(stringTextBox.Text)
    strResultTextBox.Text = outString
End Sub
```

The **sender** and **e** arguments are the standard signature of event handlers. Sender is the object that raised the event and *e* contains the data of the event. All events in .NET contain such arguments.

*EventArgs* is the base class of all event arguments and doesn't say much about the event. Several events use a derived class to supply more data, eg. a [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event uses the KeyEventArgs class which contains the actual key pressed in its [KeyChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx) property.

This is basic .NET programming stuff and you should spend some time understanding .NET events and Windows Forms instead of trusting auto-generated code

Comment: thanks - had a feeling that a separate private method might be required. There may still be occassions in the future when I need to call an event handler from somewhere else in my code though, or can it be avoided 100% of the time?

Comment: ...I'm studying `VB.NET` over the next couple of years for an undergraduate qualification hence this question (& lots of future one). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Sender is used to specify which object generated the event, e is the event data itself.
For example, usually when you click on a button in a form "sender" would be the button, and e would be the mouse event.

In you case you could simply change

```
Call stringButton_Click(Me, Me)
```

To

```
Call stringButton_Click(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making a new method. Do not call the event handler.

```
Public sub abcd()
Dim outString As String
Select Case stringTextBox.Text
    Case ""
        outString = "You entered an empty string"
    Case "10"
        outString = "10"
    Case Else
        outString = "Your string is not covered by the cases"
End Select
strResultTextBox.Text = outString
end sub
```

Call this method from where you want

```
Private Sub stringButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles stringButton.Click
abcd()
End Sub
```

and from this

```
Private Sub stringTextBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
 System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles stringTextBox.KeyDown
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    abcd()
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to move your code into a separate function, as already spoken above, but here's a workaround: 
`call stringButton_Click(Nothing,Nothing)`