# How Can I RaiseEvent Manually For A FileSystemWatcher

Tags: vb.net, events, filesystemwatcher, raiseevent

I have extended on the FileSystemWatcher class to incorporate a FolderCount monitor and FolderEmpty monitor that raise events if a folder reaches a specified amount of files or if a folder returns to an empty status.  I seem to have this working and I'm getting events raised when these conditions occur.

However, my problem is that when my FileSystemWatcher first initializes, it automatically goes in to check the folder contents of the specified folder to get a file count.  If the limit is already reached, I need to raise an event immediately rather than wait for the FileSystemWatcher to report it.

Currently I can only seem to raise events by plugging into the `.Created` and `.Deleted` calls, however, because no files are getting created or deleted, I don't know how to raise my event manually.

```
Public Sub Initialize()
        SetFolderCountStatus() 'Set the isFolderEmpty flag based on file contents
        If Not isFolderEmpty Then
            If options.WatchForFolderCount Then 
                If FileCountReached(options.FileCountToWatch) Then
                    RaiseEvent EventFolderCount(sender, e) 'Sender and e are never defined
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

My problem is that both `sender` and `e` are never populated with anything because they sit outside of my `WatcherEventArgs`.

I'm sure this can be done a better way, but I am unsure.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: `RaiseEvent EventFolderCount(Nothing, New WatcherEventArgs(...) )` will work, but it would be better to simply invoke a method which does the work you need which is also called by the real event(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually resolved this by changing my EventHandler to only require a `String` variable, rather than `EventArgs`:

```
Public Event EventFolderCount(filename As String)
```

This way I could call it easily inside and outside of the `FileSystemWatcher` like so:

```
RaiseEvent EventFolderCount(filename)
```

Thanks @Dave Anderson for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually use the `sender` and `EventArgs` in your `EventFolderCount` method? You can pass `Me` for the sender and an empty `EventArgs` object.

However [What are the event arguments “sender” and “e”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929529/what-are-the-event-arguments-sender-and-e) suggests attempting to raise the event isn't preferred. Instead you should have a single method that accomplishes the task and have that called in both places.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I do actually use the EventArgs to reference the `.FullPath` of the file(s).

Comment: @Riples, can you create the EventArgs with your `.FullPath` correctly set? Are you sticking with raising the event or abstracting the logic into a dedicated method you can call from both places?