# Using the EventArgs

Tags: c#, java

what is the java equivalent method "getSource()" in C# language

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{ 
   if(e.getSource().equals(button1)){
      //some code here
     }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1303176/558486

Answer (score 7):

There is not `GetSource` in C#. This is why, the UI events are usually using the signature `(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)`. The source is defined by the parameter `sender`.

Answer (score 0):

In `.NET [C#/Vb.net]`

The general signature of a `EventHandler` (`delegate`) is :

```
  public delegate void EventHandler(
      Object sender,
      EventArgs e
  )
```

Where : [`sender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) represents the : `The source of the event.`

---

So, Java Equivalent will be :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, button1))
    {
        //wohoo!!! its the same object
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How am i going to express that using the switch statement
I want something like this:

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
        switch(e.getSource()){
             case button1: // some code
                    break;
          }
        }

Comment: well .net will disappoint you a little, there is a limitation on switch case statement, you  have to go with if else - if else logic!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905/c-sharp-switch-statement-limitations-why - check this for more details!

Answer (score 0):

In .net handler is defined as follows

```
protected void btnname_event(
      Object sender,
      EventArgs e
  )
{
//handler details
}
```

sender will be equaivalent of getsource()