# SelectedIndexChanged not recognizing dynamic comboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I am making a form that has a ComboBox created at runtime. Based on the selection of that ComboBox I want to create another control that appropriately handles the user selection. In this case, it is a drop down list of Source Types. 
In Main.Designer.cs I have:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cboSourceTypes;
```

In Main.cs I have:

```
namespace DataVerification
{
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Iinitialize_MyForm();

    }
    public void initialize_MyForm()
    {
        ComboBox cboSourceType = new ComboBox();
        cboSourceType.Items.Add("ODBC");
        cboSourceType.Items.Add("CSV");
        cboSourceType.SelectedIndex = 0;
        tabMyFrom.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(cboSourceType);
        cboSourceType.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(cboSourceType_SelectedIndexChanged);           
    }

    public void cboSourceType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        switch (cboSourceType.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 1:  //ODBC - Handle this selection
                break;
            case 2:  //CSV - Handle this selection
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I try to access `cboSourceType` from inside `cboSourceType_SelectedIndexChanged`, it seems like the `ComboBox` cannot be accessed even though the code seems the same as in another project that wasn't dynamically created. How can I get `cboSourceType_SelectedIndexChanged` to recognize the `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 2):

The `cboSourceType` variable you're trying to use inside the `cboSourceType_SelectedIndexChanged()` method is local to the `initialize_MyForm()` method, so it is out of scope.

To get a usable reference to the `ComboBox`, you should cast the `sender` parameter of the method to a `ComboBox`:

```
var cboSourceType = (ComboBox)sender;
```

Once you do that, you should have a reference to the `ComboBox` that fired the event.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with scope of your ComboBox `cboSourceType`.

Explanation :

```
public void initialize_MyForm()
    {
        ComboBox cboSourceType = new ComboBox(); // Where you define it
        cboSourceType.Items.Add("ODBC");
        cboSourceType.Items.Add("CSV");
        cboSourceType.SelectedIndex = 0;
        tabMyFrom.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(cboSourceType);
        cboSourceType.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(cboSourceType_SelectedIndexChanged);           
    }

    public void cboSourceType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        // Try to access it from here : out of the scope 
        switch (cboSourceType.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 1:  //ODBC - Handle this selection
                break;
            case 2:  //CSV - Handle this selection
                break;
        }
    }
```

Solution :

Get the required combobox element from sender like follows

```
    public void cboSourceType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        switch ((ComboBox)sender.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 1:  //ODBC - Handle this selection
                break;
            case 2:  //CSV - Handle this selection
                break;
        }
    }
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303145/net-events-what-are-object-sender-eventargs-e) for more on event handling