# How casting an object works in OOps?

Tags: c#, oop, variable-assignment

I am not able to understand the following assignment  statement:

```
ImageButton btnsave = (sender) as ImageButton;
```

what it actually does?

Comment: [.NET Events - What are object sender & EventArgs e?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303145/net-events-what-are-object-sender-eventargs-e)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr

Comment: Take a look at [C# `as` opeartor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)