# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'

Tags: sql, vb.net, telerik

Error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'

Why?

```
<EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
    <FormTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Assign_t" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#3366CC">Assign</asp:Label>

    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="dd_Assign" runat="server" RenderMode="Lightweight" Skin="Bootstrap"  SelectedValue='<%#Bind("Assign_to") %>'>
           <Items>
              <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="No Assign" Value="0" />
              <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="name1" Value="email1@svi.co.th" />
              <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="name2" Value="email2@svi.co.th" />
           </Items>
    </telerik:RadDropDownList>

    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text='<%# IIf((TypeOf (Container) Is GridEditFormInsertItem), "Insert", "Update") %>' OnClick = "SendMail"
                                        runat="server" CommandName='<%# IIf((TypeOf (Container) Is GridEditFormInsertItem), "PerformInsert", "Update")%>' ></asp:Button>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                            CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>
    </FormTemplate>
</EditFormSettings>
```

```
Protected Sub SendMail(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim ddlSection As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim editItem As GridEditFormItem = DirectCast(ddlSection.NamingContainer, GridEditFormItem)
    Dim dd_Assign As DropDownList = DirectCast(editItem.FindControl("dd_Assign"), DropDownList)

    Dim strFrom As String = "emailfrom@emailfrom.co.th" 
    Dim strCC As String = dd_Assign.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim strBCC As String = "BCC@BCC.com" 'BCC
    Dim strSubject As String = "Request JOB Verification Approval" 
    Dim strBody As String = "test"
    Dim mailMessage As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(strFrom, strCC, strSubject, strBody)
    Dim mailClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("xx.xx.xx.xx", 25)
    mailClient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@email.co.th", "pass") 
    mailClient.DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    mailClient.Send(mailMessage)

End Sub
```

Comment: The `sender` parameter is the object that raised the event. Obviously you are handling the `Click` event of a `Button` there so why would the `sender` be anything else?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty straightforward: an attempt to cast a `Button` control to `DropDownList` has occurred & throwing `InvalidCastException`.

One of the button control has `OnClick` event handler which bound to `SendMail` method:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text='<%# IIf((TypeOf (Container) Is GridEditFormInsertItem), "Insert", "Update") %>' 
            OnClick="SendMail"
            runat="server" CommandName='<%# IIf((TypeOf (Container) Is GridEditFormInsertItem), "PerformInsert", "Update")%>'>
</asp:Button>
```

But inside `SendMail` method attempts to cast into `DropDownList` are exist:

```vb
' first cast
Dim ddlSection As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)

' second cast
Dim dd_Assign As DropDownList = DirectCast(editItem.FindControl("dd_Assign"), DropDownList)
```

Note that the [`sender` argument contains control object that the event action is bound for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303145/net-events-what-are-object-sender-eventargs-e), hence you need to bind the event handler into proper control. You can try casting it to `Button` to prove it:

```vb
Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
```

Since `EditFormSettings` with `Template` edit mode was used, I think you're using `RadGrid` here, so you can utilize `ItemUpdated` event instead of standard button event handler as given in [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/form-template-update/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true).

```vb
Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemUpdated(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridUpdatedEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemUpdated
    If e.Exception Is Nothing Then
       ' email sending code here
    Else
       ' throw exception
    End If
End If
```